# Counter not increment in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a button and added a click event on which data value increment by 5 
but it is appended by 5

https://jsfiddle.net/neyaz90/dkvmmrbd/

```
<div id="react">
<button @click='counter += 5'>Increment</button>
<p>{{result}}</p>
```

```
new Vue({
el:'#react',
data:{
counter:'0'
},
computed:{
  result:function(){
    return this.counter;
 }
}
});
```

please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `Number` instead of a `String` for `0` See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/64438/) here.

**HTML**

```
<div id="react">
  <button @click="counter += 5">Increment</button>
  <p>{{ result }}</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#react',
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  computed: {
    result: function() {
      return this.counter;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is defined with '0'(String) instead of 0(number).

You also don't need the computed value to show the result.

Only `{{counter}}` would be enough.